# What do I do when the wrong answer gets upvoted?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/27727/13681) asking how I could set the default page of an https virtual directory when no page was specified, since it was simply giving users a `404 Not Found` error. The top voted answer is one on how to setup https itself, which doesn't answer my question.

I tried placing a bounty on the question to get more attention, but the answer telling me how to setup https only got more upvotes. Someone did post links in the comments pointing to some other questions that were similar, however they did not answer my question either.

Is there anything I can do when I feel the wrong answer is getting upvotes? I couldn't downvote because I didn't have 125 rep (even before placing bounty).

Or perhaps I am missing something? I looked through the links provided, however they only tell me how to setup https itself, not how to set the default webpage for an https virtual directory.

Comment: I think users sometimes upvote answers when the answer is useful to _them_, irrespective of whether it answers the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an answer does not clearly address your question you may need to rephrase your question (not an issue in your case) and, if the answers presented still fail to address the information you're seeking, you should comment on the answers (as you did).

It was suggested in comments on an answer that you also consider asking at other sites in the StackExchange (SE) Network - if you feel your question would do better at another SE site, please use the "flag" link on your question to request migration, rather than re-posting your question at another site (migration is quick and preserves all the information associated with your question).